# What are the (confirmed) movie references in 'The Mitchells vs the machines'?

Tags: movie, the-mitchells-vs-the-machines

When viewing "*The Mitchells vs the Machines*" on Netflix in German, I recognized the music from "*Kill Bill*" and there seemed to be other films being mentioned (that I didn't recognise).

Have the film's makers spoken about the other references and homages that they included in their film?

Comment: This seems very broad indeed. Practically anything could be a reference or a quote if you squint hard enough

Comment: Point for you, any idea how to change the question? (or some example-question I could read as "how ro shape the question")

Comment: I'm at a loss as to how you could make this less obviously broad. Maybe asking if the creators have spoken about their references?

Comment: great idea :) I was not successfull in searching for some kind of list, so maybe someone did find such a thing

Comment: Do a google search for "The Mitchells vs the Machines Easter eggs" you will get lots of listings of references to other movies/shows/etc.

Comment: @NJhonny Would you make an answer out of it? Sometimes simple the right keywords are missing :) easter egg was not in my search terms, thank you for this!